# Wrap single node with a given node

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a `picture` variable that points to a `<img>` element in my document tree. I want to wrap with a `<span>` tag. When I do it with plain DOM functions everything works as desired:

```
var container = document.createElement("span");
container.style.border = "1em solid red";
container.innerHTML = "Container";
picture.parentNode.appendChild(container);
container.appendChild(picture);
container.style.borderColor = "green"; // Result: green on screen
```

More specifically, `container` points to the one and only `<span>`. But when I do it with the [jQuery `wrap()` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
var container = $("<span></span>")
    .css({border: "1em solid red"})
    .text("Container");
container.css({borderColor: "yellow"}); // Result: yellow on screen
$(picture).wrap(container);
container.css({borderColor: "green"});
```

... Query clones my Node and wraps the picture around the clone, thus `container` points to a node that was never used and remains detached from the document. I understand this happens because `wrap()` needs a wrapper object for each matched element in the jQuery chain (cloning makes full sense).

Is there an elegant jQuerish way to wrap a single `<img>` tag with a given `<span>` and keep a reference to such `<span>` for further use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var picWrapper = $(picture).wrap(container).parent();
```

Once you wrap it in `span`, the `span` element will be it's new parent.